# How to make a Container draggable even if it is containing a SpanButton?

Tags: codenameone

It seems the use of a SpanButton in a draggable Container breaks something since the Container can no longer be dragged. What can be done to still have the Container draggable even with a SpanButton?

I've tried to understand the CN1 code, but difficult for me to follow. My guess is that the culpit is that a SpanButton makes its internal Button Lead of its own Container, but I don't see why that should prevent containing Containers to have another Lead at their level.

I also noticed in the test code below (1st example) that setting a Container draggable doesn't work unless some (arbitrary?) content within it is made Lead. Not sure why, I haven't found any explanation in the documentation or here on SO.

```
Form hi = new Form("SpanButton ", BoxLayout.y());
{
    Button button1 = new Button("Normal Button, no lead");
    Container draggableContainer = BorderLayout.centerCenterEastWest(button1, new Button("Other"), null);
    draggableContainer.setDraggable(true);
    hi.add(draggableContainer);
    //observation: container not draggable 
}
{
    Button button2 = new Button("Normal Button, lead");
    Container draggableContainer = BorderLayout.centerCenterEastWest(button2, new Button("Other"), null);
    draggableContainer.setDraggable(true);
    draggableContainer.setLeadComponent(button2); //undocumented why a draggable Container doesn't work without a LeadComponent
    hi.add(draggableContainer);
    //observation: container draggable 
}
{
    SpanButton button3 = new SpanButton("SpanButton, lead");
    Container draggableContainer = BorderLayout.centerCenterEastWest(button3, new Button("Other"), null);
    draggableContainer.setDraggable(true);
    draggableContainer.setLeadComponent(button3);
    hi.add(draggableContainer);
    //observation: container not draggable (well, "Other" can initiate a drag, but container disappears
}
hi.show();
```

Comment: By the way, I have draggable containers with SpanButtons in my app since quite some time and it worked until recently. So, it may be recent changes in CN1 which broke this. I can't be sure, but the test code above seems to indicate it could be a regression in CN1.

Comment: We made some changes to the lead component behavior a couple of months ago.  Possibly this commit https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/78ce7d61e25b91f6d5cf44eeebaa544843bc64b5 I'll ask about that

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I tried to follow the code in debug mode, and I got the impression that maybe the reason is that when LeadUtil.leadParentImpl(Component) is called from Component.isDragAndDropOperation(int x, int y) to search for a lead container, the search goes depth-first, which will then pick up an embedded lead component (like the SpanButton) which is not set to draggable. The isDragAndDropOperation code was modified in March by Steve so time-wise that could correspond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added this test case to our samples, and have made some modifications so that it works correctly now.
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/37d12f8e749b258c7afb9fd66810a34153567b54
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/261aeabc933d3020253d6ea552098e77bb32973d

These will be included in the update tomorrow.

Comment: Super, thanks Steve and Shai! I've tested with your changes it and my code works again.